# Unable to call custom function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, static, namespaces, public

I'm trying to retrieve permutation set based on a string. However, i couldn't execute the function properly. I'm not really good with public static, or private or how should I call the function.

```
<?php namespace Helpers;

class Helper {

public static function permute($str,$i,$n) 
{
   if ($i == $n)
       return "$str\n";
   else {
        for ($j = $i; $j < $n; $j++) {
          swap($str,$i,$j);
          permute($str, $i+1, $n);
          swap($str,$i,$j); // backtrack.
       }
   }
}

public static function swap(&$str,$i,$j) {
    $temp = $str[$i];
    $str[$i] = $str[$j];
    $str[$j] = $temp;
}}
```

This is how I call the function from my controller.

```
Helper::permute($str,0,strlen($str))
```

I'm getting this error:

> Call to undefined function Helpers\swap()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the method `swap()` and `permute()` from a static context, but handle them as if they were non-static.
Try changing it to the following:

```
public static function permute($str,$i,$n) 
{
    if ($i == $n)
        return "$str\n";
    else {
        for ($j = $i; $j < $n; $j++) {
            self::swap($str,$i,$j);
            self::permute($str, $i+1, $n);
            self::swap($str,$i,$j); // backtrack.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed the method of call for 3 lines into self:: but wonder why it's not returning any value.